# Where would the knock sensor be on a 1998 Dodge Grand Caravan SE 3.3 L 6 cylinder

Tags: dodge, knock-sensor

So, my father owns a Dodge grand caravan, 1998, but it will not start. We have replaced the starter, the ignition switch, and even got a few new fuses. We have also replaced the battery, because the cold winter killed it.  There were no errors when we tested fuses, and it worked before the winter set in. There was a   cold snap, the battery died, and would not properly work, and after the winter, we are trying to fix it. When you try to crank the engine, there is no sound except for clicking, and we tried a safer version of crossing the starter terminals, which resulted in the engine trying to start, but it did not start. We do not think that it is the result of bad wiring, but the knock sensor. Where would it be located on a 1998 Dodge Grand Caravan SE, 3.3 Liter engine, 6 cylinder? If it does not have a knock sensor, what might the problem be?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It sounds like your ignition switch is at fault.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I also have had trouble finding an accurate diagram of the engine, if you know where one is, could you put in a link somewhere?

Comment: Also, how would I know if it is indeed the ignition switch? We have already tried many different things, and at this point, if we run into another problem, we are just going to scrap it. We just want to be sure that it is indeed what it is we are replacing/fixing

Comment: I dont know for sure, but the knock sensor would throw a specific code as well as let your engine start. I'm not sure how you came to the conclusion it would be the knock sensor. I just think you are looking in the wrong direction.

Comment: I think you need to do a voltage drop test on the starter cables.  If it cranks by jumpering the starter terminals, but not with the ignition switch, it's indicative of bad cables.  Or a bad solenoid/starter - if you have repeated clicks when turning the key, it's the cables.  One click only and it's bad terminals inside the starter.